# Fastest way to convert a dict's keys & values from str to Unicode?

Tags: python, unicode, graph, dictionary

I'm working with a counter `from collections import Counter` and I want to print its values using `matplotlib.pylot`.

When I try to do it using:

```
plt.bar(range(len(cnt)), cnt.values(), align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(cnt)), cnt.keys())
plt.show()
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: matplotlib display text must have all code points < 128 or use Unicode strings

That's why I'm trying to convert the Counter dictionary keys to Unicode.

Comment: Doesn't sound like this is the bottleneck of your application. I would go for the cleanest / most obvious rather than the fastest.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using Python 2.7, you can use a dict comprehension:

```
unidict = {k.decode('utf8'): v.decode('utf8') for k, v in strdict.items()}
```

For older versions:

```
unidict = dict((k.decode('utf8'), v.decode('utf8')) for k, v in strdict.items())
```

(This assumes your strings are in UTF-8, of course.)

Comment: Could you tell me more about what you did? .. it confuse me a little the for inside the Dict..

Comment: The first uses a [dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), the second a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to create an iterator of tuples from which the [`dict` constructor](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) can build a new dictionary. They're analogous to [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 1):

So, i thought the op asked for unicode, not for UTF-8. Unicode is not an encoding, it's just actual text. So would this not be more accurate and/or readable?

```
unidict = {unicode(k): unicode(v) for k, v in strdict.items()}
```

Comment: If your default string encoding is UTF-8 this is exactly equivalent to the other answer. The `unicode` constructor behaves identically to the `decode` method on `str` objects. I just think it's more helpful to be explicit about the fact that `str` objects are *encoded* in a specific encoding (explicitly assumed to be UTF-8 in my answer), and converting them to `unicode` objects requires *decoding* them, which is something that trips up a lot of users conceptually.