# Ignore Unicode vs Str, Int vs Long in Python/Django Unit Tests

Tags: python, json, django, unit-testing, unicode

I'm writing unit tests for some of our code and I need to compare a JSON response with a dictionary value returned via code. The dictionary keys and some values are raw byte strings: `str` whereas the HTTP Response data, after `json.loads` have unicode keys and values. When I use `self.assertDictEqual(expected, actual)` I end up with a ton of differences!

It looks like `json.loads` can take an [`object_hook`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956867/how-to-get-string-objects-instead-of-unicode-ones-from-json-in-python) and return byte strings, but I was wondering if Python/Django `UnitTest` framework has a simpler solution.

Edit: The [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705274) solves my original problem - I tried it and it works! Now, I'm facing a similar issue with `int` vs `long`: `u'user': 86160L != u'user': 86160`. Is there an intelligent comparison mechanism that accounts for these differences - basically forces conversions to `unicode` and `long` if it detects the corresponding key/value is of this type?

Also, How do you deal with these issues while writing TestCases?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to switch to Python 3, where everything would be `str`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala He he, that's not an option at the moment!

Comment: The wording in the questions are different, but the possible duplicate seems to cover essentialy what you want to do.